# Why TnsPing only use sqlnet.ora but not tnsnames.or?

Tags: oracle

Windows 7.

I kept getting Ora err can not resolve tns name while I have all the verified good names resides in tnsnames.ora. There are more than one Oracle in my PATH, maybe that's the reason. So I used tnsping to find out.

tnsping myserver

here is the output:

```
Used parameter files:
C:\oracle64\product\12.1.0.2\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
```

the tnsnames.ora is in the same folder as sqlnet.ora, why tnsping is not using it?

Comment: What is the content of your sqlnet.ora file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, maybe, you haven't set the `TNS_ADMIN` env. variable, so `tnsnames.ora` file cannot be found. Not only with TnsPing but with everythin else, setting this variable pointing to the folder is the *only* way to consistently use the same tnsnames file.

Comment: I do have this TNS_ADMIN variable, it's pointing to a diff folder, `C:\Oracle\ODP_home1\network\admin`.

Comment: Is that also the location of your tnsnames.ora file?

Comment: As far as I remember the ODP.NET Managed Driver does not use the environment variable (at least not as first priority). So your advice may not be sufficient in **any** case.

Comment: @Alfabravo, your hint on `TNS_ADMIN` helped solving the problem. Basically, I have multiple Oracle folders like I said above, the TnsPing used the 1st one found in PATH while `TNS_ADMIN` points to a later one inside of PATH. After updating the tnsnames.ora in this folder, worked.

Answer (score 0):

It actually might have used your tnsnames file. `tnsping` only prints a message like

```
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
```

when it finds a match using `tnsnames`.

You might look at setting some of the [diagnostic parameters in `sqlnet.ora`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF397) to trace the issue in more detail.